# Show item in context menu for specific filetype only using Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool

Tags: nautilus

Is it possible to show menu item in context menu for specific filetype only using Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool?

For example, I am have `FFmpeg` installed in my Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to execute it only for mp4 filetype.